# Is there a way to flag that a progressive web app requires a hardware keyboard?

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps

I know that the whole concept of PWA is for a app to scale across all screen sizes I have written an IDE-like application (in a PWA), that is information dense, and I want my PWA to be portable across desktop OSs (mouse + keyboard), and tablets (touch + hardware keyboard).

My app is not really meant for mobile OSs. There are many keyboard short cuts, and whilst I could add UI elements to simulate these key presses, the screen is already action packed enough. The app simply doesn't belong on any platform without a hardware keyboard. But PWAs (with the hardware keyboard filter) are the perfect method of distribution for desktop OSs with modern browsers, so I'm in a bit of a pickle.

So, my question is - is there a way for a progressive web app (via the manifest or otherwise) to signal requires (or works best) with a hardware keyboard?

Comment: Can you try to remove the icons used for an smartphone? Does it still work as a pwa on that device then?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer - No Explicit way** to find the availability of physical keyboard programmatically or to restrict your app to keyboard only devices by requesting browsers/search engines to make that restriction with any kind of meta data/scripts. Said that, you can't restrict the user by putting in the URL or your PWA web page in the address bar and requesting for it. All you can do is, on loading, you can do some checks like in the "alternate solution" and show a message to the user to use a computer with keyboard attached. If the soft keyboard is good enough to handle your checks, you are left with no luck!

[There are some tricky solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203050/html5-detect-presence-of-physical-keyboard-in-javascript) developers have experimented.

**Alternate solution:** Unfortunately, nothing you can rely on, without asking the user itself. 
On loading your app(or when ever you think it is appropriate to), prompt the user to press one of the shortcut, which you think its more appropriate for a user with physical keyboard. Wait for the even listener of that key combination. If the event is caught, then you can assume, user's keyboard is good with your shortcut solutions. Also give a button "Shortcut pressed" and another button "Not available in my keyboard" and on pressing, you can let the user know the app id not for them or even you can let them use it with mouse and menu option(which is more appropriate).

Comment: The question isn't about whether a physical keyboard is present, but whether it's possible to make sure that my PWA is not listed or presented on devices without a physical keyboard (or access to one). I know that PWAs are all about being portable to any device, but sometimes it's enough to be portable across devices that satisfy well thought out pre-requisites (such as for a coding based PWA to require a hardware keyboard).

Comment: NO. You cant restrict. PWAs are end of the day regular websites, which users find though various sources and access with your URL in the browser and later may add it to home screen and access from there. Browser/Search engine or any other such referring factor wont give you the choice to filter websites based on such hardware capability.

Comment: @Chris did this answer clarifies your question ? If not, let me know what’s still not clear.

Comment: I think this answer is technically correct, but it's answering the wrong question. It seems to be answering about whether it's possible to detect a hardware keyboard or not in JavaScript, rather than the question I was asking, which is, is it possible to create a PWA for "desktop-like" (platforms with a hardware keyboard) only. I think the answer as of May 2018, is that no, it isn't possible. That said, I think it's a weakness in the spec right now. For now, and given that this is an answer to a different question, I'm going to leave this open for future solutions.

Comment: Can you please explain how you aim "Create PWA for desktop-like platforms" only" ? In which part you are aiming to specify the restriction?From all I know of web, you can't make any restrictions without the help of JavaScript and related meta tags. That's the reason for highlighting limitations in JS. How would you stop a search engine to not display your site when a user is searching for a surface pro for example when the physical keyboard is disconnected and magically show in results once he connects the keyboard? ...

Comment: How would you stop browser loading your web page when the user types in the URL in address bar? All you can do to restrict is on loading your page, using the code in your page, you can show some message saying users device is not eligible for using your web page. For you to say that, you need JS and kind of solution that I was explaining. Remember, PWA is nothing more than a web application which loads in browser and its bound to web standard limitations. All I'm saying is, there is no web standard to support what you are asking and the kind of JS solution I've mentioned is all you can do.

Comment: I already have a solution for warning that the application requires hardware keyboard. The question is simply about categorizing a PWA in its metadata, that a hardware keyboard is a requirement. I'm happy that the spec currently does not support this requirement. Kind of odd actually when there are all kinds of filters available to apps in the App Store and Play Store, even down to specific hardware. PWA is ideally a fully portable app, but where there are specific device requirements, it makes sense to be able to express this is metadata (given that Microsoft has started scraping apps).

Comment: I added a +1 for your answer, and discussion, and I appreciate it, but I'm going to leave this open, as I honestly think this is an omission in the spec, and an answer (that is impossible to answer now) will present itself in the next year or two. But, honestly, thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171494/discussion-between-anand-and-chris).

Comment: While I've started a chat discussion for you to state what specific use-case you are trying to avoid, I could see you also agree this is a feature that doesn't exist now and you are hoping to see in a year or two. StackOverflow will only get you whats answer at that given time. If it changes in future, someone will come and add it here eventually regardless of this question status. If you are more interested in getting this feature, request it in W3C mailing list and follow though community's response to it. https://www.w3.org/Mail/. That's the right way to get new web spec features added.